# Tomcat does not respond by IP in the same machine but does in the network

Tags: tomcat, networking, windows-8.1

I have a tomcat7 installation on a Windows 8.1 PC (named pc-A). Tomcat does not respond by IP address from machine A (works using localhost) but responds to requests by IP from another PC in the same network (named pc-B), i.e. if I open a browser on pc-B and I write http://ip-A:8080 I can see the tomcat welcome page; If I do the same thing on pc-A I get I page cannon be loaded message.

I tried shutting down windows firewall and writing down ip-A in the hosts file.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can try to shutdown the Proxysettings.

Comment: There is no proxy :(

Answer (score 0):

I think your installation is binded to your local PC in the config.

Open the  tomcat/conf/server.xml file and search for some text like:

```
<Connector 
    port="8080" 
    protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
    address="127.0.0.1"
    ...
```

If you find the address attribute, remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked out my configuration and there was no adderss attribute in any connector :(